# Pass argument to anonymous function in environment file angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass parameters to an anonymous function in my enviornment file, wihch should replace the `${}` with the parameter passed in, but it is not working as expected, so I must be doing something wrong.

Here is my file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  endpoints: {
    customer: {
      test: (searchTerm: string) => 'http://localhost:7071/api/Customer/SearchCustomerBySearchTerm/${searchTerm}',
    },
  }
};
```

I call this anonymous function from my service as follow:

```
const url = environment.endpoints.customer.test('aaa');
```

When I hit the breakpoint in my backend service, the searchTerm passed through is `${searchTerm}`, and I actually passed in 'aaa'.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the wrong quotes. A template literal must be delimited by backquotes:

```
test: (searchTerm: string) => `http://localhost:7071/api/Customer/SearchCustomerBySearchTerm/${searchTerm}`
```

Comment: Geeze, not sure how long it would have taken me to realize that.  Last thing I looked at.